# Returning largest value in linked list

Tags: c++, list

I had posted a question on this earlier today, but it was pretty vauge so am now providing more details.

I am trying to return the largest value from a linked list, but it is only returning the first value I input?

Structure:

```
struct Stock{

string itemName;
int itemStock;  //100 crisps etc...
double individualItemCost;
double totalSockValue;
Stock* next;
```

};

How the function is called:

```
Stock * g = Largest(head, sizeOf);
cout << "Name: " << g->itemName << " Stock: " << g->itemStock << endl;
```

The actual function:

```
Stock* Largest(Stock*& list, int size)
```

{

```
Stock *current;
current = (list+0);// start_ptr; 
int largestValue = 0;
if (current!=NULL)
{
    while (current->next!=NULL)
    {
        if (current->itemStock < largestValue)
        {
            largestValue = current->itemStock;
            current = current->next; 
        }
        else
        {
            current = current->next; 
        }
    }
}
return current;
```

}

It is returning the first value I input as opposed to the largest value, any advice would be helpful.

This is how I am reading it into the linked list just so you know:

```
while (i < sizeOf)
{
    cout << "Please enter the students name: " << endl;
    cin >> head->itemName;
    cout << "Please enter the item stock: " << endl;
    cin >> head->itemStock; 
    cout << "Please enter the item price: " << endl;
    cin >> head->individualItemCost;    

    push(head,head->itemName, head->itemStock, head->individualItemCost);  //Push back everything in head
    i++;

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
    if (current->itemStock < largestValue)
    {
        largestValue = current->itemStock;
        current = current->next; 
    }
    else
    {
        current = current->next; 
    }
```

regardless of which branch your code takes, `current` will always be set to the next element of the list. Since you return `current` you'll return the last element of the list, regardless of what the largest values found is.

I'm not going to spoon feed you the solution, but I'll give you a hint: You need an additional variable of type `Stock*` that's being used very much like the variable `largestValue`.

Comment: Right ok cheers, so you mean something like setting a variable of type stock to current->itemstock, and then returning that?

Comment: Almost. Just `current` without the `->itemstock`.

Comment: Ah! I think I have not got it working!! Thankyou for your help, have been stuck on this for a long time haha. Just one last Q, I now have memory leaks as I am initlising this Stock* temp;
 temp = new Stock;, is there anyway to do it without using dynamic variables?

Comment: @user2799788: Why are you allocating a new Stock object? You don't need to create a new Stock instance. I can pretty much guess how your code looks. Trust me (and try to understand), that is suffices to write just `Stock *temp;` and not to use the `new` operator. – This whole thing reeks homework, and I'm pretty sure the point of the assignment is to make you understand pointers.

Comment: Ah gotcha, yeah I really did not need to create a dynamic variable....just set it to first value in list. Thanks for your help! +1

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to return the largest value, and yet, you test whether a value is less. Your current code looks like this:

```
if (current->itemStock < largestValue)
{
    largestValue = current->itemStock;
    // (...) 
}
```

Which is logically equal to "from two values, select the smaller and set it as the largest".

On top of that, you're iterating thru the whole list without even remembering which stock is the largest, if you just need the number - return `largestValue`, not `current`.

Comment: Yes ofcourse haha, I have been editing previous code and have obviously missed that simple thing; thanks for the realisation!